# SFINAE compilation error involving nested templates

Tags: c++, templates, g++

I have a nested template class of a graph and node(s) where the nodes are only defined within the context of the graph template parameter. Furthermore, the new nodes can be spawned out of existing input nodes. I have implemented this via SFINAE to enforce that the member functions only accept nodes of appropriate types as below:

```
// Type your code here, or load an example.

#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct graph
{

template <typename U>
class node;

template <typename U>
static constexpr std::true_type check_node(node<U> const&);
static constexpr std::false_type check_node(...);
template <typename V> static constexpr bool is_node_v = decltype(check_node(std::declval<V>()))::value;
template <typename... Args> static constexpr bool are_nodes_v = (is_node_v<Args>&&...);

};

template <typename T>
template <typename U>
struct graph<T>::node
{

// COMPILES defined inside class body
// template <typename... Nodes, typename V = U, typename std::enable_if_t<graph<T>::template is_node_v<typename graph<T>::template node<V>> && graph<T>::template are_nodes_v<Nodes...>,V>* = nullptr>
// auto operation(Nodes const&... nodes) -> node<V>
// {
//     return node<V>();
// }

// ERROR if defined out-of-line as  the following
template <typename... Nodes, typename V = U, typename std::enable_if_t<graph<T>::template is_node_v<typename graph<T>::template node<V>> && graph<T>::template are_nodes_v<Nodes...>,V>* = nullptr>
auto operation(Nodes const&... nodes) -> node<V>;

};

// ERROR if defined outside class as the following
template <typename T>
template <typename U>
template <typename... Nodes, typename V, typename Enable>
auto graph<T>::node<U>::operation(Nodes const&... nodes) -> node<V>
{
    return node<V>();
}

int main() {
    auto gr = graph<int>();
    auto nd = graph<int>::node<int>();
    nd.operation(nd);
}
```

The compiler outputs the following error:

```
<source>:37:6: error: no declaration matches 'graph<T>::node<V> graph<T>::node<U>::operation(const Nodes& ...)'
   37 | auto graph<T>::node<U>::operation(Nodes const&... nodes) -> node<V>
      |      ^~~~~~~~
<source>:26:6: note: candidate is: 'template<class T> template<class U> template<class ... Nodes, class V, std::enable_if_t<(graph<T>::is_node_v<node<V> > && graph<T>::are_nodes_v<Nodes ...>), V>* <anonymous> > graph<T>::node<V> graph<T>::node<U>::operation(const Nodes& ...)'
   26 | auto operation(Nodes const&... nodes) -> node<V>;
      |      ^~~~~~~~~
<source>:22:18: note: 'struct graph<T>::node<U>' defined here
   22 | struct graph<T>::node
      |                  ^~~~
Compiler returned: 1
```

The only way that's worked for me was to define the function inside the class body, as commented. I was wondering if I could get help with what is making the code ill-formed? Thank you very much.

Comment: which line is line 31? This one `auto operation(Nodes const&... nodes) -> node<V>` ? The definition is commented out, but for a declaration a `;` is missing

Comment: indeed your current error is just about a missing `;` but there is more https://godbolt.org/z/nc776KnP1

Comment: Yes that was a mistake on my part, that revision is indeed what I wanted to ask about.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to my question, which is that all the template parameters must be deduced and/or defaulted. In my case having the parent `<T>` nested parameter was not satisfying this.

```
include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct graph
{

template <typename U>
class node;

template <typename U>
static constexpr std::true_type check_node(node<U> const&);
static constexpr std::false_type check_node(...);
template <typename V> static constexpr bool is_node_v = decltype(check_node(std::declval<V>()))::value;
template <typename... Args> static constexpr bool are_nodes_v = (is_node_v<Args>&&...);

};

template <typename T>
template <typename U>
struct graph<T>::node
{

template <typename... Nodes, typename W = T, typename V = U, typename std::enable_if_t<graph<W>::template is_node_v<typename graph<W>::template node<V>> && graph<W>::template are_nodes_v<Nodes...>,V>* = nullptr>
auto operation(Nodes const&... nodes) -> node<V>;

};

template <typename T>
template <typename U>
template <typename... Nodes, typename W, typename V, typename std::enable_if_t<graph<W>::template is_node_v<typename graph<W>::template node<V>> && graph<W>::template are_nodes_v<Nodes...>,V>* ptr>
auto graph<T>::node<U>::operation(Nodes const&... nodes) -> node<V>
{
    return node<V>();
}
```

The following works!